# Change of variables in 3 dimensions

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the following integral:

> $$\int_{|x| = \epsilon} \phi(x) \frac{e^{-m|x|}}{4 \pi |x|^2} d^3x.$$

I wanna show that this integral goes to $\phi(0)$ for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. The idea is to swap to spherical coordinates:

$$\int_{|x| = \epsilon} \phi(x) \frac{e^{-m|x|}}{4 \pi |x|^2} d^3x = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{S^2} \phi(x) \frac{e^{-m\epsilon}}{\epsilon^2} \epsilon^2 d\Omega = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{S^2} \phi(x) {e^{-m\epsilon}} d\Omega $$ Now we wanna substitute $$y = x/|x|$$

$\frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{S^2} \phi(x) {e^{-m\epsilon}} d\Omega = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{S^2} \phi(\epsilon y) {e^{-m\epsilon}} d\Omega $

The last step is where I'm not sure what happens. Somehow the infinitesimal variable should change aswell, but I'm not quite sure how.

Could somebody make that clear for me?

Cheers!

Comment: I'm confused.  The $d^3x$ suggests that we're integrating over a three-dimensional space, but the space $\{x:|x|=\epsilon\}$ is two-dimensional.

Comment: Oops, that's a typo. We are in 3 dimensional space though.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're missing is the relation

$$d\Omega = \sin{\theta} \, d\theta \, d\varphi$$

where $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ and $\varphi \in [0,2 \pi]$.  Your integral looks like

$$\frac{e^{-m \epsilon}}{4 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} d\varphi \, \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, \sin{\theta} \, \phi(\theta,\varphi)$$

As $\epsilon \to 0$, the numerator goes to $1$, and your are left with the average value of $\phi$ over the sphere, which by the mean value theorem for the sphere, takes the value at the center of the sphere, or $\phi(0,0)$.